# sed - matching escape char, backslash+double quote

Tags: sed, escaping

I'm trying to find replace the following

```
<a href=\"test\">
```

with

```
<a href="test">
```

using sed.

I understand that both the `\` and the `"` need to be escaped, so I do the following:

```
sed -i "s|a href=\\\"test\\\"|a href=\"test\"|g"
```

but this doesn't seem to work.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use single quotes instead of doubles.

```
$ echo '<a href=\"test\">' | sed "s|a href=\\\"test\\\"|a href=\"test\"|g"
<a href=\"test\">

$ echo '<a href=\"test\">' | sed 's|a href=\\\"test\\\"|a href=\"test\"|g'
<a href="test">
```

Ori, if you can't use single quotes, just add even *more* escapes :-)

```
$ echo '<a href=\"test\">' | sed "s|a href=\\\\\"test\\\\\"|a href=\"test\"|g"
<a href="test">
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it works even though I can't use it as the real string I'm working with also includes single quotes!

Comment: @EoghanM, I've posted another non-single-quote solution - it's just a matter of adding more escapes since the shell itself will suck up one level.

Comment: Thanks- that did it! 5 backslashes! I actually tried up to 4 but thought I was getting ridiculous!

Comment: @EoghanM, no probs, I thought I'd better solve it properly since you'd accepted it. And you're right, it _is_ ridiculous but that's not _your_ fault, so much as the UNIX way of doing things :-)